# How can I call on multiple variables to determine their average only if they exist?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I have multiple loops like this:

```
HPBL = grbs[15].values
lat = input('Enter lat:')
lon = input('Enter lon:')
print 'PBL Height:',HPBL[int(lat),int(lon)],'m'
HGT_1000 = grbs[256].values
if HGT_1000[int(lat),int(lon)]<HPBL[int(lat),int(lon)]:
    UGRD_1000 = grbs[260].values
    VGRD_1000 = grbs[261].values
    UGRD_1000_val = UGRD_1000[int(lat),int(lat)]
    VGRD_1000_val = VGRD_1000[int(lat),int(lat)]
    wind_1000 = math.sqrt(UGRD_1000_val**2+VGRD_1000_val**2)
    print '1000mb wind is:',wind_1000,'m/s'
else:
    print '1000mb winds not below PBL'
```

Where the end goal is to print an average of wind_1000, wind_975, wind_950, and etc but only if each wind_xxxx variable has a value. Per the loop, I have it skip if the 'if' requirement is not met. 
So what I am having trouble thinking of is how I would go about computing the average

```
wind_ave=np.mean(wind_1000,wind_975,wind_950,...wind_xxx)
```

but of course my problem is that the wind variables won't always have a value per the if loops. How can I compute the wind_ave only if the wind_xxx variables have values to them?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
total = 0
n_inputs = 0
while my_loop_condition:
    if there_is_a_value:
        total += value
        n_inputs += 1
average = total / n_inputs
```

which can also be done in numpy with: `my_values[~np.isnan(my_values)].mean()` if missing values are coded with `np.nan`.